# How to read the numeric value of a byte?

Tags: bash

I would like to read some byte values. This command

```
printf '\x00\x01\x02' | how
```

should print this:

```
0
1
2
```

I tried this:

```
printf '\x00\x01\x02' | while read -rN1 BYTE ; do echo "?" ; done
```

but I do not know how to get the numeric value of the byte.

Comment: The problem appears to be that '\00' is treated as a terminator.

Comment: @ams Yes I think so, too. Stupid C string. I have to change my example.

Answer (score 5):

Use `printf` instead of `echo`.

```
printf '\x01\x02' | while read -rN1 BYTE ; do printf '%d' "'$BYTE" ; done
```

Notice the single quote preceding `$BYTE` in the argument to `printf`; that tells `printf` to print the ASCII value of the character, not the character itself.

Comment: +1 for the tricky use of `"'$BYTE"` but it doesn't work for `printf '\x00\x01\x02'`

Comment: In between v4.2 and v4.3, there was a change in how `read` handles `NUL`s in the input, which (perhaps inadvertently) affects `read -N1`. Since 4.3, `NULs` are simply ignored unless they happen to be the line delimiter; however, `read -N` ignored the delimiter so there is now no exception; `NULs` are always ignored. From this I conclude that chepner is using bash-4.2 while @anubhava has upgraded to bash-4.3. There is a version which works with both, though: `while IFS= read -d '' -rn1 BYTE; do`

Comment: 4.3, actually. However, I just sidestepped the whole issue of null bytes in my answer, to focus on the char-to-ASCII conversion. Good to know how various versions of `bash` handle the null byte, though.